# wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) - When i try to add data in rails admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) in rails admin when i tried to add data's from backend , I have attached screenshot, Please do see that and help me out!

Please visit https://imageshack.com/i/n7dz4up

Comment: That screenshot is practically illegible. You should show the section of code in question and the error message in your post.

Comment: “Romantics Anonymous” — cool bookmarks bar, bro.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is going to blow your mind, so have a seat, then read on.

## You passed two arguments to a method that only expected to get one.

If you need more help be sure to come back with more details, like the code and what you've done to fix the problem so far!